# Passing jQuery Autocomplete search method value to search event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am making a call to the search method and passing a value

```
$('myelem').autocomplete('search','test');
```

Then I have an event handler for the search event

```
search: function (event,ui){

//I need to access the value 'test' passed from the search method in the search event

}
```

So far I can not find out how to access the value in the search event handler. The value is available in the `source: function (request, response)` event handler in the `request.term` property.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation reads:

```
search: function(event, ui) { ... }
```

However, the ui parameter turns out to be an empty object.